# Volume of a solid of revolution: $y = x^3$, $y = x^{1/3}$, $x \geq 0$ rotated about $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to find the volume:

> Rotate about $y$.
>   $$y = x^3,\quad y = x^{1/3},\quad x \geq 0$$

Simple enough.

$x = y^3 \implies x = y^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$$\pi \cdot \int_0^1 y^{(1/3)^2} - y^{3^2}dy$$

$$\pi\cdot \left(\frac{3}{5} - \frac{1}{7}\right)$$

Of course that is wrong, why?

Comment: your question is not clear...

Comment: What do I need to clarify?

Comment: Are you trying to find the volume?

Comment: Yes of course. I will add that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas My book gets twice that quantity and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Two possibilities (i) You are right and the book is wrong or (ii) Your description of the region and the book's are not equivalent. One can also do it by cylindrical shells. In this case this is a bit messier. Same answer of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Since you're using the disk method, your solution is correct, given the problem as stated. But be careful with notation: note the difference between the squaring of the functions as shown below. You evaluated as it should be evaluated, so the result is correct.

$$\pi \cdot \int_0^1 \left(y^{1/3}\right)^2 - \left(y^{3}\right)^2\,dy = \pi \int_0^1 y^{2/3} - y^6\,dy$$

Which, integrating and evaluating, gives you

$$\pi\cdot \left(\frac{3}{5} - \frac{1}{7}\right) = \frac{16\pi}{35}$$

Comment: But I am using the disk method, the 2 isn't needed is it?

Comment: If you are using the disk method, then you are correct, and there is a typo in the text's solution. Else, perhaps there are additional constraints?

Comment: the radius of the outer function is $f_1(x)$ so the area of the disk is $\pi[f_1(x)^2]$ and then we remove the inner disk with radius $f_2(x)$ whose area is $\pi[f_2(x)^2]$ which is why you get an answer with just $\pi$